# What happens to app name if android:label is not specified in android manifest?

Tags: android, label, android-manifest

I have the following in my android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="nis.history_card_game" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/history"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".Battlefield">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChooseHero">
    </activity>
</application>
```

For some reason my app is called **nis.history.card_game** So what happens if in application tag `android:label` is missing?

Comment: You answered your question. If `android:label` is missing it gives the app name as your package name. `android:label` is your application name which appears in launcher.

Comment: Additionally, most launchers will look for Activity labels, if one isn't found for the application. In System Settings, though, it will show as your package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the activity tag with the attribute android:label is not necessary, except you want make the activity the title different with the application label, you can use your own label. the default should be as same as the application label.

**Elements of the AndroidManifest.xml file**

The elements used in the above xml file are described below.

> **manifest**

manifest is the root element of the AndroidManifest.xml file. It has **package** attribute that describes the package name of the activity class.

> **application**

**application** is the subelement of the manifest. It includes the namespace declaration. This element contains several subelements that declares the application component such as activity etc.

The commonly used attributes are of this element are **icon**, **label**, **theme** etc.

**android:icon** represents the icon for all the android application components.

**android:label** works as the default label for all the application components.

**android:theme** represents a common theme for all the android activities.

> **activity**

**activity** is the subelement of application and represents an activity that must be defined in the AndroidManifest.xml file. It has many attributes such as label, name, theme, launchMode etc.

**android:label** represents a label i.e. displayed on the screen.

**android:name** represents a name for the activity class. It is required attribute.

> **intent-filter**

intent-filter is the sub-element of activity that describes the type of intent to which activity, service or broadcast receiver can respond to.

> **action**

It adds an action for the **intent-filter**. The intent-filter must have at least one action element.

> **category**

It adds a category name to an intent-filter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know **WHY** this happens - in case android:label attribute is missing, the system automatically assigns the package name. No idea why this happens - might be just convention from Google.

But the solution is just to add label in  tag, not above!