# What will be the name after downloading from Play Store if not specified android:label?

Tags: android, google-play, package-name, application-name

When I instal an app from a local machine directly to the phone without specified *android:label* in manifest, it will show **package name** instead of application name. I know that.

But what will happen if I download an app from Play Store where the application name is specified but without *android:label*?
What will be displayed instead of application name (**package name** from the code or an **application name** from Play Store)?

Comment: If android:label is missing it gives the app name as your package name.  - You can look for answer by - [What happens if android label is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627845/what-happens-to-app-name-if-androidlabel-is-not-specified-in-android-manifest)

Comment: [@Nitish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16796366/nitish), even if I downloading from Google Play Store with specified name on the application page?

Comment: `application name from Play Store` this is only to show app name is Play store, You can even changes this name without any new release and changes will only reflect in play store. Installed app will  refer to android:label or package name. Probably you could test this using beta release or internal testing release in play store to be 100% sure.

Comment: Please add few screenshots to make your question more clear

Comment: @Nitish already answered my question. Thank you!